# Get all milestones in GitHub Enterprise repository

Tags: github, github-api

How I can get a list of all milestones into GHE repository using Eclipse client. I tried this but there is a param number that I can't find:

```
        GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(host);
        client.setOAuth2Token(token);

        RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);

        List<Repository> repositories = service.getRepositories();

        for (int z = 0; z < repositories.size(); z++)
        {
            Repository repository = repositories.get(z);

            MilestoneService milestoneService = new MilestoneService(client);

            List<Milestone> milestones = milestoneService.getMilestones(repository, "");

        }
```

Comment: 1. What is "GHE"? 2. I don't understand the question, what is the param number that you can't find?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari GHE -> GitHub Enterprise